# Open android browser in InAppBrowser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Using the following code opens InAppBrowser. I would like to open the other browsers like Chrome and anything that comes with Android.

```
   var data = '<form id="Form" action="http://www.example.com/api/form/" method="post">' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="' + firstname + '">' + 
        '<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="' + lastname + '">' +
        '</form><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("Form").submit();</script>';

        var pageContentUrl = 'data:text/html;base64,' + btoa( pageContent );
        let browser = new InAppBrowser(data, '_blank', 'hidden=no,location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
```

**target**: The target in which to load the URL, an optional parameter that defaults to _self. (String)

- **_self**: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.
- **_blank**: Opens in the InAppBrowser.
- **_system**: Opens in the system's web browser.

So therefore, your code with _system should do what you want

```
let browser = new InAppBrowser(data, '_system', 'hidden=no,location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
```

You should read the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/)